# Order result according to result of a function

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use below query but occur error that

> invalid column name money

```
select * from (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by money desc) as row,
                            ChargeLog.customerCode,(select taraz from getCustomerMoney(ChargeLog.customerCode)) as money
                             from ChargeLog 
                            )tblTemp
                            WHERE row between  (1 - 1) * 20 + 1 AND 1*20
```

Comment: Are you sure, getCustomerMoney(ChargeLog.customerCode) will return only 1 value?

Comment: Can you share tables schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH T AS 
(   SELECT  ChargeLog.customerCode,
            (select taraz from getCustomerMoney(ChargeLog.customerCode)) as money
            from ChargeLog 
), T2 AS 
(
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by money desc) as row,
          customerCode,
          Money
          FROM T           
)
SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE row between  (1 - 1) * 20 + 1 AND 1*20
```